# Lua interpreter for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lua, interpreter, coronasdk

I am trying to run lua code in the Eclipse simulator.
The LuaEclipse plugins are installed and updated, but Eclipse is asking for a "Lua interpreter" when I try to run the code.

If I set the Lua Interpreter to the CoronaSimulator.exe then Eclipse will properly run the Lua code in the Corona Simulator. However, I want to run the Lua code in the Eclipse simulator!

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can only use a normal command-line lua interpreter... Corona has its own internal Lua interpreter integrated with its own code in its own ways, it will not behave the way you are expecting.